# Looping through Firebase database to build a table list in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table view. Inside it has a table cell. I want my clients to show up in the list. The clients list comes from Firebase Database.

So, I setup the table views and define an empty client array

```
class ClientViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var clients = Array<Any>()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clientsCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = clients[indexPath.row] as? String
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return clients.count
    }
```

Once the view is loaded, *(which I'm pretty sure is the problem)* I itterate through a database reference and append the company name to the empty clients array

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var ref: DatabaseReference!

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("clients").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for client in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let company = client.childSnapshot(forPath: "company").value
                self.clients.append(company ?? "No company name")
            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

If I hard code the clients array, it works great. With this I think the iteration happens after the table is generated. How can I get this working like I need it too?

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop reload the table

```
for client in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
    let company = client.childSnapshot(forPath: "company").value
    self.clients.append(company ?? "No company name")
} 
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

---

Also avoid `Any` type if you eventually will cast to `String`

```
var clients = [String]()
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you